# Access to `types` of `rules` of `photos` attribute of model

Tags: php, model, yii, rules, yii1.x

I use `Yii 1`. (I am ashamed!)

Model:

```
<?php
class GalleryForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $photos;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('photos', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true,),
        );
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
$model = new GalleryForm();
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'photos',
    'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',
    'max'=>10,
));
```

How can I access to `types` of `rules` of `photos` attribute of model?
I need use `jpg, gif, png` string in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:

```
$types = null;
$validators = $model->getValidators('photos');
foreach($validators as $validator) {
    if ($validator instanceof CFileValidator) {
        $types = $validator->types;
        break;
    }
}
echo $types; //jpg, gif, png
```

And extra codes:

```
$types = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', explode(',', $types)));
var_dump($types);
//array
//  0 => string 'jpg' (length=3)
//  1 => string 'gif' (length=3)
//  2 => string 'png' (length=3)
```